# Distinct ipv4 subnet/supernet from the entries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Good day,

I would like to distinct the subnets/supernet from the entries of my table.
For example, to get only 10.40.3.0/24, 10.41.3.0/24, and 10.42.3.0/24 by one query. Right now I'm using this query to generate the output below (please note that this is a small portion of the entire dataset).

```
SELECT * FROM copy_tcp_3 WHERE  dst_ip << '10.40.0.0/11' AND vlanid = 11 ORDER BY dst_ip;

   src_ip    |    dst_ip    | protocol | dst_port | vlanid
--------------+--------------+----------+----------+--------
 10.72.21.221 | 10.40.3.105  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.40.3.105  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.10   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.11   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.11   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.12   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.13   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.13   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.18   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.20   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.20   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.20   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.21   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.21   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.26   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.26   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.27   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.28   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.30   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.31   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.31   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.33   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.38   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.48   |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.159  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.226  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.41.3.226  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.226  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.41.3.227  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.41.3.228  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.134  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.222  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.227  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.42.3.227  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.228  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.42.3.228  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.230  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.42.3.230  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.42.3.231  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.232  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.233  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.236  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.42.3.236  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.42.3.237  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.223  | 10.42.3.237  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.3.237  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.3.224  | 10.42.20.42  |        6 |     7680 |     11
 10.72.21.221 | 10.42.20.42  |        6 |     7680 |     11

SELECT DISTINCT(dst_ip) FROM copy_tcp_3 WHERE  dst_ip << '10.41.0.0/11' AND vlanid = 11 ORDER BY dst_ip;"
    dst_ip
--------------
 10.40.3.105
 10.41.3.10
 10.41.3.11
 10.41.3.12
 10.41.3.13
 10.41.3.18
 10.41.3.20
 10.41.3.21
 10.41.3.26
 10.41.3.27
 10.41.3.28
 10.41.3.30
 10.41.3.31
 10.41.3.33
 10.41.3.38
 10.41.3.48
 10.41.3.159
 10.41.3.226
 10.41.3.227
 10.41.3.228
 10.42.3.134
 10.42.3.222
 10.42.3.227
 10.42.3.228
 10.42.3.230
 10.42.3.231
 10.42.3.232
 10.42.3.233
 10.42.3.236
 10.42.3.237
 10.42.20.42
 10.42.25.80
 10.43.3.222
```

Please note that I'm working with INET as type:

```
 column_name | data_type
-------------+-----------
 src_ip      | inet
 dst_ip      | inet
 protocol    | integer
 dst_port    | integer
 vlanid      | integer
(5 rows)
```

Can you kindly check my question and advise me please?

Thank you in advance.
With kind regards
Farzad

Comment: If you want to summarize, then use the `network(inet)`.  You may need to first set the mask lengths with `set_masklen(inet, length)`.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-net.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, thanks to Mike I found a solution:

```
psql -U postgres -d tcp -c "SELECT DISTINCT(network(set_masklen(dst_ip, 24))) FROM copy_tcp_3 WHERE  dst_ip << '10.40.0.0/11' AND vlanid = 11;"
    network
---------------
 10.40.3.0/24
 10.41.3.0/24
 10.42.3.0/24
 10.42.20.0/24
 10.42.25.0/24
 10.43.3.0/24
```